# Prevent multiple logins using the same credentials

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I checked previously asked similar Questions, but I am not able to find a suitable answer.

Requirement: On two different machines the same user credentials can't be used to access the application.

What I have implemented, At the time of login, logout from all previous devices used by user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

class UserAccount(models.Model):
    """
    This model will be used to extra user information.
    """

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, db_index=True)
    session = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    ip_address = models.IPAddressField()

def logout_other_devices(user, request, **kwargs):
    """
    Delete session(logout all) other devices with same credential.
    """

    profile = user.useraccount

    if profile.session:
        Session.objects.filter(session_key=profile.session).delete()

    profile.session = request.session.session_key
    profile.ip_address = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    profile.save()


user_logged_in.connect(logout_other_devices)
```

What still is left, if one user is logged in one system and passes its `sessionid` (from cookies) to the second user connected under the same WiFi(or LAN) connection then the IP of second is coming same on server. How can I discriminate the second user and log-out the first user before allowing access to any website data to the second user.

Answer (score 9):

Django generates a session key and saves it in the db everytime a user logs in. If user logs in from another browser/device Django creates a new session key without deleting the old one.

If you want to log the user out of other devices, you just need to delete his/her previous session key from db.

Since there is no easy way to identify which key belongs to which user, you will have to save the session key in user model after the user logs in. So, add another field in your User model called `session_key`, like so:

```
# models.py

class UserAccount(...):
    ...
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

You will also need to make some changes to your login view, like so:

```
# views.py

from django.contrib.sessions.backend.db import Session

def login_view(request):
    ...
    user = authenticate(...)
    
    # Here comes good part

    if user is not None:

        if user.session_key: # check if user has session_key. This will be true for users logged in on another device
            try:
                s = Session.objects.get(session_key=user.session_key)
            except Session.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            else:
                s.delete() # delete the old session_key from db

       login(request, user) # log the user in

       # set new session_key for user instance
       user.session_key = request.session.session_key
       user.save() # save the user

    # do other stuff
```

Comment: function logout_other_devices doing the same task as you said. Updating the new session and deleting previous associated with that user.

My point if someone copies that `sessionid` from cookies pass to another user then there is no need to login. New user will be treated as login as user.

Comment: @AnkitSachdeva Oh! Okay. Will update the answer if I come up with something.

Answer (score -1):

This is should work over here

#models.py

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class UserSession(models.Model):
    user_acc = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    session_maneger = models.OneToOneField(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from .models import UserSession

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def remove_other_sessions(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    Session.objects.filter(usersession__user=user).delete() # removing user other session

    request.session.save() # here is the saving users current session

    # create a link from the user to the current session (for later removal)
    UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
        user=user,
        session=Session.objects.get(pk=request.session.session_key)
    )
```