# How to reject login when user already has a session in django

Tags: python, django

In my django application I want to reject a user login if he has already an active session.
How can I do that? I tried some attempts using user_logged_in signals. Should I do this check login form with confirm_login_allowed() before new session creation?
My current setup is like that:

accounts/signals.py

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def check_existing_session(sender, user, request, **kwargs):

    session_key = request.session.session_key
    user.set_session_key(session_key)
```

accounts/models.py

```
  def set_session_key(self, key):
        self.last_session_key = key
        self.save()
```

Comment: What exactly you mean by saying "reject"? Hide login button/link or do something else?

Comment: this might help [Prevent multiple logins using the same credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286973/prevent-multiple-logins-using-the-same-credentials)

Comment: Showing some error on the login form that says "User test_user has already logged in"